# VBA Word. How to find first empty cell in Word table?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been trying to find the first empty cell in Word table using VBA.

[image: find cell in word table]

The code which I've put below finds all the empty cells instead I want to find the first one after filled one. How to solve this problem?

```
For Each oRow In Selection.Tables(1).Rows
For Each oCell In oRow.Cells
    If Selection.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
    oCell.Select
    'Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
        MsgBox oCell.RowIndex & " " & oCell.ColumnIndex & " is empty."
    End If

Next oCell
Next oRow
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
Sub FindNextBlank()

    Dim Tbl As Table
    Dim TblRow As Row
    Dim HasText As Boolean
    Dim LookForText As Boolean, Done As Boolean
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim Txt As String

    LookForText = True
    With ThisDocument.Tables(1)
        For R = 1 To .Rows.Count
            Set TblRow = .Rows(R)
            For C = 1 To TblRow.Cells.Count
                HasText = (Len(TblRow.Cells(C).Range.Text) > 2)
                If HasText = LookForText Then
                    If LookForText Then
                        LookForText = Not LookForText
                    Else
                        Done = True
                        TblRow.Cells(C).Range.Select
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next C
            If Done Then Exit For
        Next R

        If Done Then
            Txt = "Cell #" & C & " in row " & R & " is free."
        Else
            Txt = "No free cell was found that" & vbCr & _
                   " follows one that has text."""
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Search result"
End Sub
```

`For ... Each` is faster but I instinctively distrust it because the sequence of items in them is usually determined by the sequence of their creation. That may or may not be top to bottom, left to right. Calling cells by their coordinates may take a little longer but you retain control of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, it's helped me

Answer (score 0):

As you may have discovered, determining an empty cell in Word is not as straightforward as it might appear.  The code below looks for the first cell where the length of the text in the cell is 1 after removing any spaces, tabs and vbCr.  You might extend this to also look for vbLF, manual line breaks and other characters that might be in a cell but not visible if you have view text markers turned off.

The .Cells method of a table range is the most appropriate tool to use here because it will work even if the table has merged cells.  Searching a table using the cell coordinates will fail if there are merged cells in the table.  Using the .Cells method the table is searched from Top Left to Bottom right (row by column).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim myCell As Word.Range
    Set myCell = FirstEmptyCell(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range)
    myCell.Select

End Sub

' Returns the first cell that has a text length of 1
' after removing spaces and tab characters from the cell text
Public Function FirstEmptyCell(ByVal TableRange As Word.Range) As Word.Range

    Dim myCell As Word.Cell
    For Each myCell In TableRange.Tables(1).Range.Cells

        Dim CellText As String
        CellText = myCell.Range.Text
        CellText = Replace(CellText, vbTab, vbNullString)
        CellText = Replace(CellText, " ", vbNullString)
        CellText = Replace(CellText, vbCr, vbNullString)

        If Len(CellText) = 1 Then

            Set FirstEmptyCell = myCell.Range
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really much simpler than the other 'answers' suggest:

```
Dim i As Long
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
    With .Tables(1).Range
    For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
      With .Cells(i)
        If Len(.Range.Text) = 2 Then
          MsgBox " Row " & .RowIndex & ", Column " & .ColumnIndex & " is empty."
          .Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
          Exit For
        End If
      End With
    Next
    End With
  Else
    MsgBox "No table selected", vbExclamation
  End If
End With
```

I've even added some error checking.

Comment: Thank you, your solution's helped me